# Java SoapMessage add empty namespace

Tags: java, xml, soap, namespaces, element

I am calling third party soap where each element must have a namespace. I am calling from Java to a .NET service. In some elements, I must include "http:/abc.com". Other times, I must include xmlns:"". For example;

```
<GetYears xmlns="http://example.com">
  <oCar xmlns="">
    <make xmlns="http://example.com">Ford</make>
    <model xmlns="http://example.com">F250</make>
  </oCar>
</GetYears>
```

I am using javax.xml.soap.*

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        ...
        QName bodyName = new QName("http://example.com", "GetAircraftDueListItems");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElement = soapBody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
        QName qName = new QName("", "oCar");
        SOAPElement carEement = soapBodyElement.addChildElement(qName);
```

By default, this produces the following output which is rejected by the service because the namespace "" is missing on oCar.

```
<GetYears xmlns="http://example.com">
  <oCar>
    <make xmlns="http://example.com">Ford</make>
    <model xmlns="http://example.com">F250</make>
  </oCar>
</GetYears>
```

It appears that an empty namespace is ignored. Is there a way to force the element to include xmlns=""?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to somehow force to show an empty `namespace`. See also the [java docs for QName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) for the `toString()` function:

> The commonly accepted way of representing a QName as a String was
> defined by James Clark. Although this is not a standard specification,
> it is in common use, e.g. Transformer.setParameter(String name, Object
> value). This implementation represents a QName as: "{" + Namespace URI
> + "}" + local part. **If the Namespace URI .equals(XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI), only the local part is returned**. An
> appropriate use of this method is for debugging or logging for human
> consumption.

`NULL_NS_URI` on the other hand is defined in the [java docs for XMLConstants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html) as:

> Namespace URI to use to represent that there is no Namespace.
> Defined by the Namespace specification to be "".

So this is by design. Maybe you can somehow configure the third party soap to accept empty `namespaces`? Otherwise maybe checking for empty `namesspaces` and using a dummy or default `namespace` could do the trick.